# show $\int g\log (g/f)$ is $0$ only if $g=f$ almost everywhere

Tags: analysis, self-learning

> Question: Suppose that $f$ and $g$ are two probability density functions, show that $\int g\log (g/f)$ is always non-negative and equals to $0$ $\it only\ if$ $\ g=f$ almost everywhere.

I have two questions here. First, what does it mean by "only if", please? Should I prove from the former to the latter or from the latter to the former, please? Second, what does it mean by "almost everywhere" and what is the implication for this particular question, please? Thank you!

Comment: What if $g=0$ and $f=1$?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Sorry, should be positive functions.

Comment: What if $g=1$ and $f=2$? Isn't the integral negative?

Comment: @EmanuelePaolini Sorry, should be probability density functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means for every two functions $f$ and $g$ with $f\neq g$, $\int g\log (g/f)$ is non-zero.

Here almost everywhere means for all sub-sets of the sample space which can be assigned a positive measure.